# Can I use would rather with nouns or verb-ings?

Tags: phrase-usage

If yes, how can I do it?

If no, what is the alternative expression to do it?

> I'd rather make a juice *from* these vegetables than boil them.

I know the above sentence is correct but can I say this:

> I'd rather eat vegetables than meat.

Now, the word **meat** takes the place of the word **boil** so I replaced one of the two verbs with a noun. Is that okay?

> I'd rather tea than eating.

I know that's wrong but how can I say it using different expression to make it correct?

Comment: *I'd rather **drink** tea than **eat.*** Alternatively, *I'd rather **have** tea than [have] **food.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second sentence is correct

> I'd rather eat vegetables than meat.

Your third sentence is incorrect since it lacks a verb for "***tea***".

To express what you are seeking, you might use

> I'd rather be **drinking** tea than eating.
>   I'd rather **drink** tea than **eat**.

Answer (score 2):

The general format following "I'd rather" is"

> I'd rather (verb 1) [(noun 1)] [than [(verb 2)] (noun 2)].

Information inside square brackets i.e.[] is optional. Prepositional phrases and adverbs can be fitted around this format. Where verb 1 and verb 2 are the same, verb 2 can be omitted.

As your first two sentences fit within this format, they are acceptable. You last sentence does not, as it is missing verb 1, so it is incorrect.

Examples:

> I would rather stay.   I'd rather (verb 1).
>
> I would rather stay home. I'd rather (verb 1) (noun 1).
>
> I would rather stay than go. I'd rather (verb 1) than (verb 2).
>
> I would rather stay home than go to the movies. I'd rather (verb 1)
>   (noun 1) than (verb 2) (noun 2)
>
> I would rather eat vegetables than meat. I'd rather (verb 1) (noun 1)
>   than (noun 2)